# How do you get to to the admin area of GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

Ever since Gitlab changed their UI, I can never find out how to get to the admin area? How do you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UI is bad. And it's getting worse.

```
https://gitlab.acme.net/admin/
```

Is the easy way.

The other more complex way,

- Click on your Gravatar in the Left Bar.
- Click your User Name in the popup menu. This should take you to, https://gitlab.acme.net/myusername
- Click on the far right the profile icon to go to the admin area.

  [image: profile icon]

Answer (score 1):

- In the left bar click on `Search or go to...`
- In the dialog click on `Admin Area`

[image: search or go to]

Comment: I wonder where they even got the idea to do this. They moved an option from the navigation bar, to a new navigation bar that's only visible if you click on the Search Box.. This is hideous.

Comment: This option isn't even there for me. My server requires re-authentication to go to admin mode, when I go to `/admin` it gives me the option to login, however when I search for "admin" or "admin mode" or "Enter admin" I get nothing. I think this option is only available if you're already re-authenticated to login as an admin. Which just raises the question how do you authenticate as an admin to enable this option.